# Appccelerate distributed event broker with NServiceBus

Tags: nservicebus, bbv.common.eventbroker

How do I set up my NServiceBus v4 Transport layer so that it can be consumed by Appccelerate.DistributedEventBroker?

I guess I have all the necessary nuget packages installed:

- NServiceBus
- NServiceBus Host
- NServiceBus Interfaces
- T4Scaffolding.Core
- Appccelerate.Eventbroker
- Appccelerate.Fundamentals
- Appccelerate.DistributedEventBroker
- Appccelerate.DistributedEventBroker.NServiceBus

Is there any information available on the interweb to set up NServiceBus in this specific way?

Comment: Steffe, I'm the author of that library. Can you describe more your problem, then I'll come up with an example

Comment: Include the version of appccelerate you are using. Quick note: make sure that Appccelerate.DistributedEventBroker.NServiceBus is scanned by NServicebus and there is an endpoint mapping for each app which uses the distributed event broker

Comment: I just started experimenting with the libraries. I would like to know if there is a working example available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used AppCelerate but since NSB 4 supports domain events in form of "in memory" messages I find no need in using anything else than NServiceBus itself.

Comment: Remember the difference between Appcelerate approach, when you exchange events between already instantiated objects, and NServiceBus, where a handler gets instantiated for each message within child container. So if you, for example, want to send messages within rich client application, I would still choose Appcelerate.